# how this reload method works and what exactly it is used for?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am working on a hybrid application using ionic 3 and Angular 4.
My problem is
when user gets registered on the app by email and password he is getting a verification link on that email, after he clicks on the verification link, i want the page gets refreshed and user will be redirected to the home screen. I searched about it then i got this reload method but there is no description about this method.

firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()

Please Help

Comment: `User.reload()` reloads the user profile data from the servers. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload. But it sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the chances that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for you comment, this was my first question on stackOverflow i will follow your advice in future :)